# Get all Jira Issues for a specified Project

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am using Jira REST API to get all the Issues in Jira for a specific Project.  I don't want to have `maxResults=50`, which is the default. I just want to retrieve all issues for the project. Here is my command:

```
{ my $result = `curl -D- -u $usernameData:$passwordData -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://jira.alm.mentorg.com:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=HDS&maxResults=1000&fields=summary"`;}
```

I set `maxResults=1000` and if I remove it, it will be set by default to 50!  I just want to get all the Issues without having to worry about the maxResults. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 12):

1. Set the maxResults to a ridiculously high value e.g. 5000
2. Make an extra call just to fetch the total records quickly, without actually fetching any content

   > http://jira.alm.mentorg.com:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=HDS&maxResults=0

Comment: "The maximum number of users to return (defaults to 50). The maximum allowed value is 1000. If you specify a value that is higher than this number, your search results will be truncated." https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/groupuserpicker-findUsersAndGroups

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course we can help. :D The answer is you cannot NOT worry about the `maxResult` field. There should however be another field in the return of the REST API that shows the total count. I don't remember what it was exactly but maybe `total`?

This is an API feature and you will have to manage it. 'pagination' is there to optimize data volumes and flow. Check the [JIRA REST API Docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/).

Answer (score 4):

I have just tried to pass **-1** value to **maxResults** and got all the issues for the specific project. Not sure if this is a bug, which will be removed in next releases, but for now it works.. I am using *JIRA v.6.2.2#6258*
Call: `/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=[project_ID]&fields=*none&maxResults=-1`

So the next step would be to count returned array

Comment: I see, that using -1 as maxResults defaults to 1000. I did try with project that had over 5000 issues in it.

Comment: @Lauri thank you for telling. I guess my answer is wrong then

Comment: @Boris it could be, that in your jira maxResults is configured to be something else than 1000 and that is why you got all your issues returned. However I don't recollect any way to get ALL the issues without paging, in case the number of issues exceeds _maxResults_ configured in your JIRA

Answer (score 1):

You are able to change the maxResults if you are not a cloud user:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/changing-maxresults-parameter-for-jira-rest-api-779160706.html